# "The hardware ID does not match the one designated on the software license" error connecting to Server 2008 via RDP

Tags: windows-server-2008, rdp

I have two Windows 10 Pro computers that connect to a Server 2008 Remote Desktop server.  They have been connecting sucessfully for a few weeks.  Just recently, one PC started displaying a "The hardware ID does not match the one designated on the software license" error when I try to connect via RDP.  Then, few days later, the other PC started doing the same thing.

I believe I can solve this by deleting the MSLicensing key on the PC and have it re-created on the next connection.  This will take another RDP license from the server, but my original license should be freed up after some period of time.

Why would both PC's start displaying this message?  Is it related to a Windows 10 update?  Perhaps the Windows 10 Anniversary update?

Comment: I had this exact same thing happen right after installing the Windows 10 Anniversary update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do think this is related to the Windows 10 Anniversary update, but I don't know any details.  It looks like you already resolved the problem, but for anyone else, here's what fixed it for me:

In regedit, delete this key and its sub keys: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\MSLicensing`.

Then run Remote Desktop Connection Manager **as Administrator**, and it will re-create the MSLicensing key for you.